# Global alerts handling with @angular/material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-services

How am I meant to handle alerts in `@angular/material`?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class AlertsService {
  alerts: string[];

  constructor(private snackBar: MdSnackBar) {
    this.alerts = [];
  }

  public add(alert: string, action?: string, config?: MdSnackBarConfig) {
    this.alerts.push(alert);
    // console.warn('AlertsService::alerts =', this.alerts, ';');
    this.snackBar.open(alert, action, config);
  }
}
```

Then I have modules which use it, like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SomeComp1Component } from './some-comp1.component';
import { AlertsService } from '../alerts/alerts.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [SomeComp1Component],
  exports: [SomeComp1Component],
  providers: [AlertsService]
})
export class SomeComp1Module { }
```

https://github.com/AlecTaylor/material-alerts-ng

Is this a best practice way of handling alerts?

Comment: I was thinking of having a bell in the navbar or footer which glows red, clicking it brings up a sidebar of alerts (ala Microsoft Azure)

Comment: You'll probably want your `AlertsService` to be provided by your app module so that its app-wide. The snackbar seems fine...  maybe open up the sidebar of alerts when the snackbar action is clicked? To answer your question, there is no baked in "alert best practice" with Angular Material. It operates at a component-based level. However, maybe something in [this document](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#) could help.

Comment: Agreed with @WillHowell.